# Can I add onclick to list items with Ajax, jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code works properly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('./record.json', function (data) {
        var studentsHTML = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function (index, student) {
            studentsHTML +='<li>' + student.name + '</li>';
        });
        studentsHTML += '</ul>';
        $('#students').html(studentsHTML);
    });
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('./record.json', function (data) {
        var studentsHTML = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function (index, student) {
            studentsHTML +='<li onclick="showSubject(' + student.subject + ')">' + student.name + '</li>';
        });
        studentsHTML += '</ul>';
        $('#students').html(studentsHTML);
    });
    function showSubject(subj) {
        alert(subj);
    }
});
```

It gives the error message:
"ReferenceError: showSubject is not defined"

A simple alert() function works, but only with the 'index' parameter:

```
onclick="alert(' + index + ')"
```

It shows the indexes of the items properly. But nothing else. Eg.: alert does not work with "student.subject" too.

Is there a way to make my list elements clickable?

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: because your click looks like this when rendered:  `onclick="showSubject(math)"` It is looking for the variable `math`, not the string `"math"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stated is

> showSubject is not defined

so the onclick= is not able to find your function.

When you use `onclick=` with a function, that function must be defined as a global. Defining it within the doc.ready block makes it only available within that doc.ready block, it's not global, so onclick can't find it

Move the function outside of doc.ready and it will find it.

There is also an error with missing quotes, around the argument, added in the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [ 
      { subject: "Subject1", name: "Name1" },
      { subject: "Subject2", name: "Name2" },
      { subject: "Subject3", name: "Name3" }
    ];
    
    //$.getJSON('./record.json', function (data) {
        var studentsHTML = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function (index, student) {
            studentsHTML +='<li onclick="showSubject(\'' + student.subject + '\')">' + student.name + '</li>';
        });
        studentsHTML += '</ul>';
        $('#students').html(studentsHTML);
    //});
}); 

function showSubject(subj) {
    alert(subj);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="students"></div>
```

---

As a bonus, the recommend way to do this is with *event delegation*:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // added here to confirm it's using delegation
    $(document).on("click", "#students > ul > li", function() {
        showSubject($(this).data("subject"));
    });
 
    var data = [ 
      { subject: "Subject1", name: "Name1" },
      { subject: "Subject2", name: "Name2" },
      { subject: "Subject3", name: "Name3" }
    ];
    
    //$.getJSON('./record.json', function (data) {
        var studentsHTML = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function (index, student) {
            studentsHTML +='<li data-subject="' + student.subject + '">' + student.name + '</li>';
        });
        studentsHTML += '</ul>';
        $('#students').html(studentsHTML);
    //});

    // this is now called from the delegated event handler within doc.ready, 
    // so can be defined in doc.ready instead of globally
    function showSubject(subj) {
        alert(subj);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="students"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem you have is the scope of the function and not quoting the value inside the function call. It is better to not use inline events, but to bind event listeners to the element.

You would be better off using event delegation and data attributes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // bind click handler to students, listen for clicks on li elements
  // event delegation
  $("#students").on("click", "li", function() {
    // get the li that was clicked
    var li = $(this);
    // read the data attribute
    var subject = li.data("subject");
    console.log(subject);
  });

  $.getJSON('./record.json', function(data) {
    var studentsHTML = '<ul>';
    $.each(data, function(index, student) {
      studentsHTML += '<li data-subject="' + student.subject + '">' + student.name + '</li>';
    });
    studentsHTML += '</ul>';
    $('#students').html(studentsHTML);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

inspect the li element on which you have added the onclick event.
Your onclick look like this:-
showSubject('Math')

Not like this:-
showSubject(Math)

the fix would be properly escape the quotes as shown  by freedomn-m

and it should work